# Laravel won't let me migrate a table because it already exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use Laravel Migration to create SQL tables but it won't let me.

Here is the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'mytable' already exists

Here is my code:

```
        Schema::create('mytable', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->foreign('othertable_id')
                ->references('id')->on('othertable')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('variable');
            $table->timestamps();
    });

    }

    {
        Schema::drop('mytable');
    }
```

I have also checked if other migrations are called "mytable" but they are not, so I am not sure where this come from.

I tried the following:

First

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Which gave me an error

And then I deleted the entire database altogheter and used:

```
php artisan migrate
```

And still got the error

Comment: post command you are using for migration

Comment: Are you trying to blow away all the tables and start from scratch or only add this table? The table appears to already exist.

Comment: @Sujal Patel updated

Comment: @mkaatman updated

Comment: `php artisan migrate --force`

Comment: I've facing same problem can anyone solved this issue yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `composer dump`, remove the table manually from the database and also remove the migration entry for the the table you want to remove from the migration table and rerun the migration again to see what happens.

Answer (score 14):

In laravel 5.5 and > you can use:

```
  $ php artisan migrate:fresh 
  // ( not migrate:refresh wich is a different command)
```

This command first drops all tables and then reruns all migrations

Comment: not sure why this doesn't have more upvotes. This is cleaner than manual dumping.

Comment: @publicknowledge, you are absolutely correct. It's 25th April 2021 (12:14 am) and I still find [@]Pim verleg's answer completely perfect. It solved my troubles within 8 - 10 seconds. Thank you [@]Pim verleg. The world needs more programmers like you. I'm your 12th upvoter.

Answer (score 11):

If you have the table in DB and dont want migrate create it, you can ignore it by check Schema::hasTable before create

```
public function up()
{
    if(Schema::hasTable('products')) return;       //add this line to migration file
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

}

Comment: a good solution when developer is unable to refresh tables for some reason

Answer (score 2):

I had neither removed the migration entry nor dropped the table manually from the database
In my case, the solution is open up the tinker from the composer

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> Schema::drop('users')
>>> Schema::drop('password_resets')
>>> Schema::drop('orders')
>>> exit
php artisan migrate
```

Here is the result of the above commands executed

```
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate
```

> In Connection.php line 647:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   alre     ady exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not
>   null auto_incr     ement primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null,
>   `email` varchar(255) not n     ull, `password` varchar(255) not null,
>   `remember_token` varchar(100) null,      `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null) default character      set utf8mb4
>   collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> In Connection.php line 449:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   already exists

```
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate:rollback
Nothing to rollback.
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.1.20-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Schema::drop('users')
=> null
>>> Schema::drop('password_resets')
=> null
>>> Schema::drop('orders')
=> null
>>> exit
Exit:  Goodbye.
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrating: 2018_08_18_071213_create_orders_table
Migrated:  2018_08_18_071213_create_orders_table
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$
```

Also define the method `down()`, if it doesn't exist. 
Otherwise, it'll show

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'XYZ.ABC' (SQL: drop table `ABC`)

```
/**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('ABC');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Add following line :
`Schema::dropIfExists('mytable');` inside the ***Up()*** function at the very beggining exactly before creating schema for the **mytable**. 
i.e. before following code. 
`Schema::create('mytable', function (Blueprint $table)`

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the table `mytable` does already exist in the DB. You should rollback the migration:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

And migrate again:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: @prgrm try to remove the table manually and run the migration again.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I need to dump the SQL schema,

run this command:

```
php artisan schema:dump
```

then run PHP artisan migrate command again

Answer (score -2):

go to app>Providers>AppServiceProvider.php and copy paste this at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

then go to function inside of it named 'Boot()' and copy paste this one:

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

now go to your your database and delete your database completely, then go to console:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

then create a new database with same name and go back to consol and write :

```
 php artisan migrate (congrats your database now shows em all)
```