# php artisan migrate gives error [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Tags: laravel, migration

```
[PDOException]
```

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel won't let me migrate a table because it already exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186512/laravel-wont-let-me-migrate-a-table-because-it-already-exists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.5 Error Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129270/laravel-5-5-error-base-table-or-view-already-exists-1050-table-users-already)

Answer (score 1):

drop the database then create the database again before migrating.